# `active` class not switching based on `route` update

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

on load of new `route` the active class not switching to new tab. I am not able to find the solution for this.

but the new page is loading without any issue. the only issue is the active class  not switching to new page and not remove from the old page.

how to fix this?

here is my hbs file :

```
<div class="navbar-sub-header navbar-sub-header---tab-bar" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <div class="rdc-tab-bar">
            {{#link-to "auth-page.credit-card.credit-cardno" class="rdc-tab-bar___tab"}}
                Credit Card //by default active added
            {{/link-to}}
            {{#link-to "auth-page.i-banking" class="rdc-tab-bar___tab"}}
                Online Baning //when click page loads, active not swithing
            {{/link-to}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

my router.js :

```
 this.route('auth-page', function() {
    this.route('credit-card', function() {
      this.route('credit-cardno');
      this.route('credit-otp'); //works fine
    });
    this.route('i-banking'); //not updating to active state
  });
```

**UDATE**

When I directly hit the url as : `http://localhost:4302/auth-page/i-banking` I am getting active class updated.

Comment: I have seen practically same issue when clicking on the rendered {{link-to}} elements, when using them in a tab-like setting. Cannot yet abstract away the issue into an ember-twiddle for my case. I can say that all three routes are subroutes that get built on top of parent route that has a dynamic link/slug.